# Image clipping to fit circle container

Tags: html, css

Usually I would accomplish image clipping in css using background-size: cover; but for this project I wan't to keep things explicit in the html document.

This is the html:

```
<div class="itemList">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/image.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

.item is a circular container (eg.

```
border-radius: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
color: #ffffff;
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
```

)

I set a fixed width on the image so part of it leaks from the container. The park that leaks is what needs to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `overflow: hidden;`

```css
.item {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemList">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/500/500/">
    </div>
</div>
```